# Using special pins as gpio

Tags: gpio, kernel, pi-zero-w

I would like to use `I2C` and `SPI` pins as a `gpio` on my `raspberry pi zero w`. To be more clear, *BCM 3-5-7-11-13-14* pins on the link [1]. I want to disable `I2C1`, `GPCLK0`, `SPI0`, `UART`, `PWM0`.  Is it possible and how if so? I assume I need to make changes in `dtb` files.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure all of the interfaces are disabled in 'Raspberry Pi Configuration':

[image]

or from the command line 'sudo raspi-config':

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that was easy. Does raspi-config app change the pin configuration of cpu within dtb files? Afaik, the configuration of the pins (i2c, uart etx) declared in device tree files.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure any reference to SPI, I2C, etc. are commented out in file `/boot/config.txt` (put a # at the start of the line).

Actually normally no special action is required.  The very act of setting a GPIO to be an INPUT or OUTPUT will break any existing association with SPI, I2C etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say  that best source for REAL answer is datasheet , unfortunately it is buried in this little snippet:

SYNOPSIS
The function select registers are used to define th
e operation of 
the general
purpose I/O 
pins. Each of the 54 GPIO pins  has at least two al
ternative functions as defined in section 
16.2. The FSEL{n} field determines the functionalit
y of the nth GPIO pin. All unused 
alternative function lines are tied to ground and w
ill output a “0” if selected. **All pins reset 
to normal GPIO input operation.**
Of course that implies the "alternate function" is NOT selected in raspi-config as already pointed out.

PS raspi-config IS the "official" place to setup alternate pins function - NOT boot config. BUT I did not verify that!

Comment: `raspi-config` just edits `/boot/config.txt`.  I'm not sure that it is included in any distribution other than the raspberrypi.org Raspbian based distributions.